# styling a customElement like an existing element

Tags: css, custom-element

How to style a custom element like an existing element? (For example, apply the document `<pre>` style to a `<special-pre>` custom element)

**BACKGROUND**

- typical custom elements are  based on the generic HTMLElement, in parts because the `is="special-pre"` attribute is not supported in all browsers (ie. iOS).
- page css detailed rules are not always accessible through code, for example when the main page uses a stylesheet through a CDN (CORS restriction)

I've tried through javascript to filter applicable `pre` style selectors and create a new rule for the new custom element but I hit a wall with CDN provided stylesheets - CORS restriction prevent access to individual rules.

I also thought of inserting a dummy element and use `getComputedStyle(preElement)` but it feels like a hack and messes with the user's HTML markup.

Other solutions (`::part`, `css custom properties`) require advance knowledge of the document style that will use the custom element.

Note that `<pre>` is just an example. Looking for a solution in general to make a customElement use a defined user style so that a customElement can be generic enough to be used in different pages with different stylesheets.